# Oracle SQL query to count number of time record in between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Let say I got timestamps between '14th Nov 2013 07:00 AM' and '16th Nov 2013 03:00 PM'. How to get a record for the range number of 01:00 PM to 02:00 PM in query oracle sql. The result should return 3 which means 3 times between the two timestamps.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for a count of the number of entries in a table between two timestamps then you can use this:

```
 SELECT COUNT( time_stamp ) AS number_of_timestamps
 FROM   table_name
 WHERE  time_stamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013/11/14 07:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi') AND TO_DATE('2013/11/16 15:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi');
```

Adjust time stamps and formatting masks as appropriate.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af2b9/3/0)

If you are looking for a purely arithmetic count of the number of times a period of hours occurs (i.e. 13:00 - 14:00) between two timestamps then you can create a function to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_Periods_Between (
  start_time  DATE,
  end_time    DATE,
  lower_bound NUMBER,
  upper_bound NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
 RETURN FLOOR( end_time - start_time ) + CASE WHEN start_time - lower_bound/24 <= TRUNC( start_time ) AND end_time - upper_bound/24 >= TRUNC( end_time ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END count_Periods_Between;
/
```

And then just us it in a query:

```
SELECT  count_Periods_Between(TO_DATE( '2013/11/14 07:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              TO_DATE( '2013/11/16 15:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              13,
                              14
                             ),
        count_Periods_Between(TO_DATE( '2013/11/14 07:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              TO_DATE( '2013/11/16 15:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              6,
                              14
                             ),
        count_Periods_Between(TO_DATE( '2013/11/14 07:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              TO_DATE( '2013/11/16 15:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              7,
                              15
                             ),
        count_Periods_Between(TO_DATE( '2013/11/14 07:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              TO_DATE( '2013/11/16 15:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi' ),
                              14,
                              16
                             )
FROM DUAL;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7bd7/6/0)

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a purely arithmetic calculation. To create a function and put into the query. Thanks MT0, ur answer is brilliant.